# Flutter- Expansion Panel for TextField

Tags: dart, flutter, material-ui, dart-pub, flutter-layout

Expansion Panels in flutter are great. They require header and body along with isExpanded property to be declared to be able to construct an Expansion panel. Like this:

```dart
return new ExpansionPanel(
  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded){
                   return Text('header');},  
  isExpanded: false,
  body: new Text(body[enter image description here][1]),
);
```

I want to build an Expandable TextField. I can wrap the text field with Expansion panel, and specify the TextField as Body. But there is a big white space that between header and body. Also, I would like to just expand the body and remove the header altogether, so that I can see the first Text line of body without expanding, and the rest of the body opens up when I expand the Expansion panel. Does anyone know of any work arounds for this? Or any different widget or material component I can use.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks right now, see there is a lot of spacing in between header and body.

[image]

If this questions interests you, upvote it, to draw out better answers. Flutter has a lot to come, and we need a stronger stack overflow community.

Comment: Have you tried setting `debugPaintSizeEnabled=true` like explained in https://flutter.io/debugging/#visual-debugging to track down where this comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure the `ExpansionPanel` is what you want.

If I understood correctly, you want a `Text` with two states. In the first state the `Text` has only one line, in the second state the `Text` can display all its lines. When the user taps on this widget, it switches from one state to the other.

I created a simple widget for that:

```
class ExpandableText extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandableText(
    this.data, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// The text to display.
  ///
  /// This will be null if a [textSpan] is provided instead.
  final String data;

  @override
  _ExpandableTextState createState() => new _ExpandableTextState();
}

class _ExpandableTextState extends State<ExpandableText> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _handleOnTap,
      child: new Text(
        widget.data,
        maxLines: _isExpanded ? null : 1,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleOnTap() {
    setState(() {
      _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
    });
  }
}
```

There is no animations in here so it's rather abrupt. Feel free to customize the above widget to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I figured it out eventually. I am using an ExpansionTile in place of Expansion panel to get rid of the spacing between header and body. I used bloc pattern and stateless widget to set the maxLines count, thus I achieved the result without using Stateful widget, but wit a similar approach. I have that animation issue that you mentioned. Do you know of any resources for the same. Again thank you for taking time to answer the question.